# how to set timer for physical process in Castalia?

Tags: simulation, omnet++

As the usual practice in Castalia is that the application module requests for sensor reading using requestsensorreading() function which is handled by sensor manager. Sensor manager forwards the request to physical process and the physical process replies back with its value.

What i want to do is, i want the physical process to broadcast its value at set intervals of time. Sensor device will have a sensitivity > 0 and few nodes will receive the value. How can i accomplish this? is it possible to use timerFiredCallback function and BROADCAST_NETWORK_ADDRESS inside physical process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the basic models of Castalia. The physical process is not a sensor node to send network broadcast messages. It is a module to model 
the physical process that sensors in our sensor nodes are sampling. Moreover, a Physical process does not have **one** value. Values are changing depending on space and time, and depending on the specific model you have defined (the manual has plenty of info on how to define physical processes).You could define a physical process that only returns one value for every point in space and every point in time, but I am not sure why you would like to use such a process in simulation.

A physical process does not "broadcast its value". Sensor nodes sample the physical process and based on space, time, and the specific model of the process they get a value back. Different sensors nodes might get different values back. To achieve what you want, you simply make all sensor nodes periodically sample the physical process. There are some examples of Applications that do that.

So to recap: You define how your physical process needs to behave and then you make sensor nodes sample it (from the Application module using the method `requestSensorReading()` as you already know).

Comment: yes I understand it now. thanks for clearing my doubts.